# digitalWrite best practice in Arduino

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I have a loop checking the status of a sensor. If it's in one state, I light a LED using digitalWrite (1,HIGH), otherwise, I write LOW. This happens in a tight loop many times a second.

Is it fine to write so many times, or is it better practice to set a flag and only write if the flag has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem for the board. You could also add a short delay at the end of the loop (`delay(5);`)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some benchmarking too - maybe there's a slow down if I keep calling it instead of only calling when changed.